# How to configure a custom unit test adapter for Rider?

Tags: rider, vstest

I have a custom unit test adapter whick can work well on visual studio, but I can't find any test on rider.

How to configure a custom unit test adapter for Rider?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to enable VSTest adapter support. Depending on the name of your test project, you might also need to add/modify masks for projects tests are being looked in.

[image]

Comment: Better if you show the official link as well https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Options__Tools__Unit_Testing__VSTest.html then people can get up-to-date info if JetBrains adds something new.